# R: How do I remove the first element from each inner element of a list without converting it to matrix?

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a list like that

```
[[1]]
[1] a1 b1 c1
[[2]]
[1] a2 b2 c2
[[3]]
[1] a3 b3 c3
```

I want specific element removed from each part of it:

```
[[1]]
[1] a1 c1
[[2]]
[1] a2 c2
[[3]]
[1] a3 c3
```

I tried `tail` but removes "outer" elements. Maybe some indexing would do?

Comment: Is it always the second element you want to remove? Then you could try `lapply(mylist, "[", -2)` as in `lapply(rep(list(1:3), 3), "[", -2)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the pattern is just that you want the second element removed,

```
lapply(List, function(x) x[-2])
```

Comment: Strange. I think I tried it and it didn't work that time. Now it does, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Using `purrr::map` it would be even shorter by doing

```
# setup some example data
nestedList = list(list(4,5,6),list(1,2,3))

# remove first element from each sublist
map(nestedList, tail, -1)
```