# Remove the first k-i elements from the ith entry of the list

Tags: r, list

I have a list like

```
[[1]]
[1] 4 2 3 5 8 0
[[2]]
[1] 11 -4 6 8 10
[[3]]
[1] 0 -6 9 12
```

I want the first 3-i elements removed from the ith entry of the list:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3 5 8 0
[[2]]
[1] -4 6 8 10
[[3]]
[1] 0 -6 9 12
```

A related question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858384/r-how-do-i-remove-the-first-element-from-each-inner-element-of-a-list-without-c), with however the same element to be removed from each element of the list.

Comment: I am sorry for the poor reprex, in my actual application they are not sorted.

Comment: why does the first list element start at 3? Shouldn't it start at 2? Can you brake down the process please?

Comment: It starts at three because in [[1]], the first two elements are to be removed, in [[2]] only the first is to be removed, and in [[3]] none is, so that they are all of equal length 4.

Comment: Oh, so you want to make them have equal length??

Comment: Yes, while making sure that the first elements are removed to obtain such equal length.

Comment: If you just need equal length, there's a simpler way of achieving it: compute the shortest length per list-item, then extract the tail of each list-item with the number of items equal to the shortest length.

Comment: I added an answer. Have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another idea,

```
lapply(l1, function(i)tail(i, min(lengths(l1))))
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 5 8 0

#[[2]]
#[1] -4  6  8 10

#[[3]]
#[1]  0 -6  9 12
```

**DATA:**

```
dput(l1)
list(c(4, 2, 3, 5, 8, 0), c(11, -4, 6, 8, 10), c(0, -6, 9, 12
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lapply` we could remove the first `i` elements from each list and if `3-x` is less than equal to 0 then we return the list as it is.

```
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(x) 
           if ((3-x) > 0) lst[[x]][-seq(3-x)] else lst[[x]])


#[[1]]
#[1] 3 5 8 0

#[[2]]
#[1] -4  6  8 10

#[[3]]
#[1]  0 -6  9 12
```

**data**

```
lst <- list(c(4, 2, 3, 5, 8, 0), c(11, -4, 6, 8, 10), c(0 ,-6, 9,12 ))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - unfortunately my reprex was poor so that you could exploit something in my example which is not present in my actual application. I made an edit.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I misunderstood your question first, I have updated the answer. I might gave over complicated this but it works .

Comment: Thanks, that is it, with Sotos answer indeed, imo, being a little more straightforward - sorry for the unclear initial exposition.

Answer (score -1):

Let i, j, k be the index of the first element in arrays a[], b[], c[] respectively. You remove min(a[i], b[j], c[k]) and increase i or j or k depending on where the minimum was. Repeat this as many times as how many numbers you want to remove, in thks case 3.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.